# Difficulty Adding .Lib files in VS 2010 C# Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, propertysheet

To start, I'm pretty rusty in programming.  I'm trying to link an external library (FFMpeg) to my C# forms application in VS 2010, and I'm having difficulty.  All signs point to using "Property Sheets" but mine looks more empty than everyone elses in the examples I've found online (such as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AmwIwedTCM).  This is what mine looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH9ZR.jpg .  Is there something I've been doing wrong, or did I mess up my property sheets in the past and now I'm suffering the consequences?  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add .lib files to C# projects directly. Either you have to P/Invoke them, make an interop for COM assemblies or make a managed wrapper using C++/CLI.